# Cost for a Trucking Company

Tags: calculus, optimization

Imagine you are the manager of a trucking company. One employee is to drive a truck down a $400$ mile road that has a minimum speed limit of $40$ mph and a maximum speed limit of $70$ mph. You have to pay him $\$6$ per hour, and the cost of operating the truck (in cents, not including the wages) is $12+\dfrac{x}{6}$, where $x$ is the speed of the truck in mph. What driving speed costs the least for this road?

The equations I have are $C_1(x)=12+\dfrac{x}{6}$ and $C_2(x)=600\times\dfrac{400}{x}$. These equations have different units, so how can I combine them to optimize?

Comment: Well, since one is the wage cost and the other is the operating cost and you want the total cost adding them together is the only way to combine them that gives you that.  Any other combination (say, multiplying them or raising one to another power) will only give you some abstraction that doesn't mean anything in practical terms.

Comment: Do you know how to find the maximum/minimum values of an equation?  If you do, do that.  If you don't, go back to your textbook and read up how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is over three years late, but hopefully someone else will stumble across this answer and find it helpful!

---

The equations do in fact have the same units! They look something like this (dividing everything by $100$ to work with dollars instead of cents):

\begin{align}
C_1(x)&=\frac{1}{100}(\text{cents}+\text{cents}) \\[0.2ex]
&=\text{dollars}+\text{dollars} \\
&=\text{dollars} \\
C_2(x)&=\frac{1}{100}\left(\frac{\text{cents}}{\text{hour}}\times\frac{\text{miles}}{\frac{\text{miles}}{\text{hour}}}\right) \\[0.3ex]
&=\frac{1}{100}\left(\frac{\text{cents}}{\text{hour}}\times\text{hours}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{100}(\text{cents}) \\[0.5ex]
&=\text{dollars}
\end{align}

Armed with this information, we can now add the two cost functions to find the total cost function:

\begin{align}
C(x)&=\frac{1}{100}\Big(C_1(x)+C_2(x)\Big) \\[0.4ex]
&=\frac{1}{100}\left(12+\frac{x}{6}+\frac{240000}{x}\right) \\[0.3ex]
&\bbox[5px,border:1px solid red]{=\frac{2400}{x}+\frac{x}{600}+\frac{3}{25}}
\end{align}

As always in single-variable optimization problems, we can now set $C'(x)$ equal to $0$ and find the points at which cost is minimized:

\begin{align}
-\frac{2400}{x^2}+\frac{1}{600}&=0 \\[0.2ex]
\frac{2400}{x^2}&=\frac{1}{600} \\
x^2&=1440000 \\
x&=1200
\end{align}

Wait, what? Weren't we supposed to get an answer in miles per hour that was between $40$ and $70$?

Not necessarily. All this answer means is that cost would be minimized if the truck were to drive at $1200$ mph, but that's a little difficult to achieve for a number of reasons. The best we can do in this case is to pick the value in our range of allowed values that's closest to $1200$, so we can conclude that you should have the truck driver drive at $70$ mph.

Comment: In hindsight, I realize how badly I described some of these problems. The first equation clearly makes little sense, as it would imply a fixed cost to operate the truck given a certain speed, regardless of the distance. But I really appreciate that you took the time to work through the math to find an answer, however ridiculous it turned out to be. :)

Comment: Yeah, I found that a little weird but assumed it was just a badly thought-out problem from a textbook or something like that. And thanks! I really like the idea of MSE being a repository of questions from all areas of math to which anyone of any skill level can come for help, so I'm hoping someone might someday find my answers to years-old questions helpful. (It's also a great way to put off doing my own work...)